# Converting timezone-aware date string to UTC and back in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I'm parsing the National Weather Service alerts feed into a web application. I'd like to purge the alerts when they hit their expiration time. I'd also like to display the expiration time in the local time format for the geographic area they pertain to.

The alerts cover the whole US, so I think the best approach is to store and compare the times in UTC timestamps. The expiration time arrives in the feed as a string like this: `2011-09-09T22:12:00-04:00`.

I'm using the *Labix dateutils* package to parse the string in a timezone-aware manner:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> d = parse("2011-09-18T15:52:00-04:00")
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 18, 15, 52, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))
```

I'm also able to capture the UTC offset in hours:

```
>>> offset_hours = (d.utcoffset().days * 86400 + d.utcoffset().seconds) / 3600
>>> offset_hours
-4
```

Using the `datetime.utctimetuple()` and `time.mktime()` methods, I'm able to convert the parsed date to a UTC timestamp:

```
>>> import time
>>> expiration_utc_ts = time.mktime(d.utctimetuple())
>>> expiration_utc_ts
1316393520.0
```

At this point, I feel pretty good that I'm able to convert the raw strings into a timestamp representing the expiration time in UTC. I'm able to compare the current time as a UTC timestamp to the expiration and determine if it needs to be purged:

```
>>> now_utc_ts = time.mktime(time.gmtime())
>>> now_utc_ts
1316398744.0
>>> now_utc_ts >= expiration_tc_ts
True
```

The difficulty I'm having is trying to convert my stored UTC timestamp back to the original localized format. I have the offset hours stored from the original conversion and a string I parsed to store the timezone label:

```
>>> print offset_hours
-4
>>> print timezone
EDT
```

**I'd like to convert the UTC timestamp back to a locally formatted time, but converting it back to a `datetime` doesn't seem to be working:**

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(expiration_utc_ts) + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset_hours)
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 18, 16, 52) # The hour is 16 but it should be 15
```

It looks like it's off by an hour. I'm not sure where the error was introduced? I put together another test and got similar results:

```
>>> # Running this at 21:29pm EDT
>>> utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> utc_now_ts = time.mktime(right_now.utctimetuple())
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(utc_now_ts)
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 18, 22, 29, 47) # Off by 1 hour
```

Can someone help me find my mistake? I'm not sure if it's a daylight savings issue? I came across some stuff that leads me to believe it might be trying to localize my dates and times but at this point I'm pretty stumped. I was hoping to do all of these calculations/comparisons in a timezone-agnostic manner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with python/pytz Converting from local timezone to UTC then back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465181/issue-with-python-pytz-converting-from-local-timezone-to-utc-then-back)

Comment: I would have thought you could do all this with datetime objects, and not convert to tuples or timestamps. If you make a timezone-aware "now" datetime object then just do "if x < y" to find out if the expiration date has been reached. (I realise that you were hoping to do it 'timezone-agnostic' but this way will probably be simpler).

Comment: I hoped so, too, but PostgreSQL kept wanting to localize the datetime value. (I'm sure there's a way around that, but I figured it would be easier right now to just store UTC timestamps)

Comment: I've looked at the post marked as a possible duplicate, and it didn't help. Using `localize()` got me the same result. I suspect the problem is with a DST flag somewhere that I'm not setting?

Comment: related: [How to convert a python utc datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4563272/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Daylight Savings time is being applied twice.

A trivial example:

```
>>> time_tuple = datetime(2011,3,13,2,1,1).utctimetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=2, tm_min=1, tm_sec=1, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=72, tm_isdst=0)
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time_tuple))
datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 13, 3, 1, 1)
```

I am fairly certain that the fault lies within `time.mktime()`.  As it says in its [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.mktime):

> This is the inverse function of localtime(). Its
>   argument is the struct_time or full 9-tuple (since the dst flag is
>   needed; use -1 as the dst flag if it is unknown) which expresses the
>   time in local time, not UTC. It returns a floating point number, for
>   compatibility with time(). If the input value cannot be represented as
>   a valid time, either OverflowError or ValueError will be raised (which
>   depends on whether the invalid value is caught by Python or the
>   underlying C libraries). The earliest date for which it can generate a
>   time is platform-dependent.

When you pass a time tuple to `time.mktime()`, it expects a flag on whether the time is *in daylight savings time* or not.  As you can see above, `utctimetuple()` returns a tuple with that flag marked `0`, as it says it will do in its [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html):

> If datetime instance d is naive, this is the same as d.timetuple()
>   except that tm_isdst is forced to 0 regardless of what d.dst()
>   returns. DST is never in effect for a UTC time.
>
> If d is aware, d is normalized to UTC time, by subtracting
>   d.utcoffset(), and a time.struct_time for the normalized time is
>   returned. tm_isdst is forced to 0. Note that the result’s tm_year
>   member may be MINYEAR-1 or MAXYEAR+1, if d.year was MINYEAR or MAXYEAR
>   and UTC adjustment spills over a year boundary.

Since you have told `time.mktime()` that your time is not DST, and its job is to convert all times into local time, and it is currently daylight savings time in your area, it **adds an hour** to make it daylight savings time.  Hence the result.

---

While I don't have the post handy, I came across a method a couple of days ago to convert timezone-aware datetimes into naive ones in your local time.  This might work much better for your application than what you are currently doing (uses the excellent [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) module):

```
import pytz
def convert_to_local_time(dt_aware):
    tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles') # Replace this with your time zone string
    dt_my_tz = dt_aware.astimezone(tz)
    dt_naive = dt_my_tz.replace(tzinfo=None)
    return dt_naive
```

Replace 'America/LosAngeles' with your own timezone string, which you can find somewhere in `pytz.all_timezones`.

Comment: It is incorrect. `mktime()` expects *local time* while OP passes UTC time. It fails if local timezone is not UTC. Don't use `naive_datetime_object.utctimetuple()` -- it doesn't convert it to UTC (OP uses `aware_datetime.object.utctimetuple()` that works as expected). You might need `tz.normalize()` call after `.astimezone()` if `aware_dt` is not in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.fromtimestamp()` is the correct method to get local time from POSIX timestamp. The issue in your question is that you convert an aware datetime object to POSIX timestamp using `time.mktime()` that is incorrect. Here's [one of correct ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279):

```
expiration_utc_ts = (d - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=utc)).total_seconds()
local_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(expiration_utc_ts)
```